# I have to enter twice the input before continuing program

Tags: c#, .net

I have to enter the answer twice to get the program to continue executing and I can't figure out why.
Would be great if you could help me fix it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        string inputName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} yes/no", inputName);
                Console.ReadLine();
                    //string stringy = Console.ReadLine();
                string adamsstring = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (adamsstring == "no")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Then what is your name?");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                    else if (adamsstring == "yes")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Awesome!");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game?");
                //Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for yes or 2 for no");
                    string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userValue == "no")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TO BAD!");

                }
                else if (userValue == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Good!");
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem and where is it occurring? Also, please clarify what this is supposed to do and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} yes/no", inputName);

 Console.ReadLine(); //This looks like your issue

 string adamsstring = Console.ReadLine();
```

After that WriteLine has been executed you're going to have to hit enter twice, once for the ReadLine() and a second for the assignment of adamsstring.

Although it's pretty unclear what you're actually asking, I'd remove the ReadLine() below the 'Did you type...' WriteLine.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right, you wonder why the user needs to enter their name twice.
You have two times "ReadLine()" in a row, that is why  the problem is there.

```
Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} yes/no", inputName);
Console.ReadLine();
                //string stringy = Console.ReadLine();
string adamsstring = Console.ReadLine();
```

Possible Solution:

```
Console.WriteLine("Did you type {0} yes/no", inputName);
string adamsstring = Console.ReadLine();
```